# How to only accept "y" or "n" in user's input in C++?

Tags: c++, input, cin

The code that I have made is:

```
while (*user is not closing the program*)
{
    cout << "Make a decision? (y/n) " << endl;
    cin >> userAnswer;
    ...
    if (UsersAnswer != 'y' || UsersAnswer != 'n')
        cout << "You may only type y or n.";
}
```

But when I put sentences or words like "hello" it breaks the code (outputs "make a decision?" infinite times)

Comment: Use a `while` loop.

Comment: Where does `userAnswer` come from?

Comment: @wkl that piece of code is inside a while loop

Comment: @MartinZhai it's the user's input

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: How do you put user's input into `userAnswer`? Please show that part of code.

Comment: @MartinZhai editted!

Comment: What does 'it breaks the code' mean? What happens? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @wkl editted again!

Comment: When you try to read data from a stream that does not match what is in the stream, the stream enters an error state. Until the error state is `clear`ed, the be stream cannot be written or read. since you do not check to ensure `cin >> userAnswer;` did not fail and clear the error, the loop tries to read, fails, an loops forever.

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware of `do-while` ?

```
do
{
    std::cout << "Yes or no yadda yadda yadda" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> userAnswer;
}
while( !std::cin.fail() && userAnswer!='y' && userAnswer!='n' );
```

Comment: Good but when I enter more than one character, it will print `"Yes or no yadda yadda yadda"` continuously until the input become empty.

Answer (score 4):

> But when I put sentences or words like "hello" it breaks the code (outputs "make a decision?" infinite times)

The reason this happens is because you entered `hello` and your code reads char by char, e.g. `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, etc. For each char it checks if it's `'y'` or `'n'` and each time it does what your code instructs to do: `cout << "You may only type y or n.";` and then restarts the loop with `cout << "Make a decision? (y/n) " << endl;`

To avoid this you could [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the rest of input if there is no `'y'` or `'n'` entered.

Other points:

- you have to make sure that you end your loop when `y` or `n` is entered
- you should check for upper case `Y` or `N` as well
- from your code it's not clear what are `userAnswer` and `UserAnswer`. If userAnswer is a [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) then you should use [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) perhaps.
- you should provide minimal code example that others can run and not some pseudo-code

Assuming that your `userAnswer` is char [you could do it this way](https://ideone.com/gjeaAQ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char userAnswer;
    while (1 /*user is not closing the program*/)
    {
        cout << "Make a decision? (y/n) " << endl;
        cin >> userAnswer;
        cout << "entered: '" << userAnswer << "'\n";
        userAnswer = tolower(userAnswer);
        if (userAnswer == 'y' || userAnswer == 'n')
            break;

        cout << "You may only type 'y' or 'n'.\n";
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```